# Rails + ActiveRecord: How do I write a condition "one or both are not true"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

In my model `Listing`, among other columns I have these two:

```
- seller_currency
- bidder_currency
```

The value of `listings.seller_currency` and `listings.bidder_currency` can be either `1` (USD) or `0` (EUR).

I am trying to get all listings, where `seller_currency` and `bidder_currency` is `0` (EUR) or at least one of them is `0` (EUR).

Is there a better way to write the condition than this?

```
Listing.where('(seller_currency=0) OR (bidder_currency=0) OR (seller_currency=0 AND bidder_currency=0)')
```

Answer (score 3):

According to your example, it is enough to fulfill at least one condition.

```
Listing.where(seller_currency: 0).or(Listing.where(bidder_currency: 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need one or condition and it covers the case where they are both 0. This way is preferable because it is a quicker query since it evaluates both columns at the same time.
Also, in case you wanted to use variables, the question mark stops sql injection.

`Listing.where("(seller_currency=?) OR (bidder_currency=?)",0,0)`